# Disallow Comments

Tags: comments

My web host has suspended my website because the comment sections of pages were being spammed so I can no longer access the site via wordpress. What files do I need to edit to switch off comments on all pages and how can I test the changes please ?

Comment: Can you access WordPress admin panel?

Comment: No the site is no longer accessible via wordpress so I need to ftp the appropriate files and upload them again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Discussion from the left sidebar of your WordPress admin panel.

On this page, uncheck the option that says “Allow people to post comments on new articles” and then click on the Save Changes.

Comment: It will only disable comments on new articles / post & not the older ones...

Answer (score 0):

To disallow comments retroactively. Got to all posts in the back end. Hit select all and bulk actions > edit. Then you can use the drop down to bulk disable comments.

Comment: I no longer have access to this site via wordpress so I need to know which files to download and edit